# MouseOver in JSF datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need some help on including a mouseover event for a datatable column in JSF. Can you please let me know how to include a popup list on mouseover a jsf column. Below is the code corresponding to my JSF column.

```
<p:column style="text-align: left;"  styleClass="foo" rendered="#{demandBean.screeRenderVo.adjustedRenderer}"  >
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText id="AdjustedID"  value="#{demandBean.dmdScreenLabelVO.adjustedValue}"/>
</f:facet>
<h:inputText id="AdjustedValueID" value="#{car.adjustedValue}" style="height: 20px;width:    50px;"></h:inputText>
</p:column>
```

Not sure how to add the mouserover event for the above column. Please Assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('td').mouseover(function(){
        var th = jQuery(this).closest('table').find('th').eq( this.cellIndex );
        if (th.attr('id') == "datatable:column3"){
            dlg1.show();
        }
        else{
            dlg1.hide();
        }
    });

});

</script>
<h:form prependId="false">
    <p:dataTable id="datatable" var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}">
        <p:column id="column3" style="text-align: left;"  styleClass="foo" rendered="#{demandBean.screeRenderVo.adjustedRenderer}"  >
           <f:facet name="header">
              <h:outputText id="AdjustedID"  value="#{demandBean.dmdScreenLabelVO.adjustedValue}"/>
            </f:facet>
              <h:inputText id="AdjustedValueID" value="#{car.adjustedValue}" style="height: 20px;width:    50px;"></h:inputText>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:dialog id="basicDialog" header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1">
    <h:outputText value="Resistance to PrimeFaces is futile!" />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would like to know if there is a way to acheive the tooltip functionality in plain jsf without Using Primefaces & Jquery. Thanks

Comment: There is no component as a dialog in plain JSF, you can probably create a custom component if you want to or write a plain javascript solution also instead of jQuery.