# Title not appearing when hovering over the column of a datatable

Tags: jsf-2, xhtml

For code similar to that below, the title does not appear when the cursor hovers over a column header.  Any ideas?

```
        <h:column title="COLUMN 1">
            <f:facet name="header" >COL 1</f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="col1" value="#{oneEntry.col1}" styleClass="al"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column title="COLUMN 2">
            <f:facet name="header" >COL 2</f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="col2" value="#{oneEntry.col2}" styleClass="al"/>
        </h:column>
```

Comment: Can you please add some css as this also can cause the glitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<h:column>` tag has no HTML 4.0 pass-through attributes as JSF generates these as nothing but `<td>` elements. And in HTML, tables consist of `<td>` elements within rows and columns are implicitly defined within the rows.

So it is liking specifying the title attribute for each particular `<td>` element of each and every row.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
   <td title="first">Cell A1</td>
   <td>Cell B1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td title="first">Cell A2</td>
   <td>Cell B2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So there is nothing like specifying an overall title for the column in HTML, you can have a title for `<table>` tag which is nothing but `<h:dataTable>`.

Or you can have title on individual data cells by adding title to your components inside that column like this:

```
<h:column>
      <f:facet name="header" >COL 1</f:facet>
      <h:outputText id="col1" value="#{oneEntry.col1}" styleClass="al"  title="COLUMN 1"/>
</h:column>

 <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header" >COL 2</f:facet>
      <h:outputText id="col2" value="#{oneEntry.col2}" styleClass="al" title="COLUMN 2"/>
</h:column>
```

which generates a `<span>` containing the value of the outputText with the title attribute.

Comment: Ravi, thanks a lot for the answer.  Based on this answer, it is my understanding that a column header is not possible via straight html.

My recollection is that jquery.tablesorter supports something like a toolip for the column header.  Maybe that is worth trying.

I tried using the primfaces tooltip, but couldn't figure out how to link it to an id for the column header.

Comment: You can look at this answer if you want to display a tooltip or dialog  on mouseover. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563004/mouseover-in-jsf-datatable/11568677

Answer (score 0):

If you use Primefaces, you can use similar code

```
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="TYPE" title="LINK-TYPE (DIRECT,TDR,TLGA)"/>
    </f:facet>

    <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{test.getLinkType()}"/>
</p:column>
```

I think that the solution to your problem is to define `<f:facet>` as you done in your example AND to put `<h:outputText>` in `<f:facet>` !

Using your example, you will obtain following code

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="COL 1" title="COLUMN 1"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText id="col1" value="#{oneEntry.col1}" styleClass="al"/>
</h:column>

<h:column title="COLUMN 2">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="COL 2" title="COLUMN 2"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText id="col2" value="#{oneEntry.col2}" styleClass="al"/>
</h:column>
```